# Sonar plugin Eclipse

Tags: java, sonarqube

Can I use Sonar plugin without others installations of Sonar ? I'm trying to use following the steps of [sonar doc](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+Eclipse) but it don't work. When I try to associate my projects the message "IDgroup empty" appears, and I can't connect when I try 'test connection'. Someone knows some better tutorial , or more specific? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To use the plugin you need a sonar sever somewhere. Do not hesitate to install the sonar server on your local machine if you do not have a central installation. It is [very simple](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade) to setup the server for local testing/usage.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be running Sonar somewhere, localhost:9000 is fine.  Then you have to do a build of this project using that Sonar.  If you are using Maven, right click on the project -> Run As -> Maven build, and put in sonar:sonar as the Goal.  This can also be done using Ant instead, but you will need a sonar target in your build.xml.  Then when you do the "Associate with Sonar" dialog, if GroupId and ArtifactId are empty, type in the correct values in those columns.

Answer (score 1):

You need a sonar installation. Without it you won't be able to use the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The Sonar user guide should clarify this question. It is not possible to use the plugin without an running sonar instance anywhere. You need to install it somewhere an analyse the project once with the sonar runner, ant or maven. 
After this procedure you are able to analyse your project locally. The reason for this precondition is the central configuration of Sonar.

[Sonar User Guide (Configuring Sonar in Eclipse)](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Sonar+in+Eclipse)