# Issue in associating simple java project with sonar-eclipse

Tags: m2eclipse, sonarqube, pom.xml

I was trying to analyze a simple java project using sonar.
Following are the things I have done so far:

1. Installed the Sonar2.0 plugin for Eclipse helios 3.6.
2. Installed the Maven plugin for eclipse.
3. After setting up the plugins, I created a simple java project .
4. Then I created the POM.xml file to enable the Maven Dependency  In that I have given the GroupId as `<`ProjectName`>` and ArtifactId also as `<`Projectname`>`
5. Then I tried to associate the project with Sonar (Using right click on Project >> Configure >> Associate with Sonar)

Here I am stuck up with a problem. When I select http://localhost:9000 as my server and I try to search this project,  "project '' with key 'projectname:projectname' not found on server" is displayed as an error

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an actual sonar-server installation. And the Analysis for your project must have run once.
Before those steps your project can't be found on the server, because your server doesn't know it exists.

See: [Sonar plugin Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556627/sonar-plugin-eclipse)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Oers. Anyway I have configured it using Ant instead of Maven