# Using the sonar plugin with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin, sonarqube

I'm trying to use Sonar to analyse my projects in Eclipse. I am currently using Maven in eclipse. I installed the Sonar Eclipse plugin as described in [this link](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse).

But when I try and associate my project with Sonar, I get an error saying:
 project  with key  not found on server.

Am I missing some steps? I started the Sonar Server before connecting to eclipse. But nothing works.
I even tried following this article ([Sonar plugin Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556627/sonar-plugin-eclipse)) but to no avail.

Please help..The Sonar documentation is not descriptive at all making it very hard for beginners like me to understand.

Answer (score 6):

You can not associate your project in Eclipse if you haven't first analysed it with Sonar (by running "mvn sonar:sonar" on your project).

Once your project has been succesfully analysed and that you can browse it in the Web UI (http://localhost:9000 by default), then you can try to associate your project within Eclipse and this will work.

Comment: "You can not associate your project in Eclipse if you haven't first analysed it with Sonar (by running "mvn sonar:sonar" on your project)." I get a whole load of errors when I do a maven build using sonar:sonar as the goal.

Comment: [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'sonar' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Comment: Now I get the following error :                                                                    [ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:2.13 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:jar:2.13: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:pom:2.13 ConnectException: UnresolvedAddressException -> [Help 1]

Comment: Purge your local repository and run the build again.